# Using WatiN with Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio, watin

I'm using WatiN in Visual Studio 2005. I want to compare the text on the web page using watin, how to do this? Assert.Istrue method does not work it gives an error. or am i missing the using directive for using the Assert method?

please suggest solution and let me know the using directive that supports assert method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to it in your project.  Then use the proper using statements.  If I remember Assert is would need "using WatiN.Core;"

Edit: Check out this page. It should  help. [http]watin.sourceforge.net/gettingstarted.html

Comment: Edit 2: WatiN I don't think works with the Express versions.  I'm not sure if that is relevant to this.